# Custom Eclipse editor: auto-complete brackets

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, editor, jface

I've created a custom editor for eclipse but I'm having trouble setting up an auto-complete feature (when a developer enters an opening bracket the editor auto-generates the closing bracket). I've looked at the java example and spent some time googling but I'm having trouble finding any information. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It will be simplier if you show us what you tried so far

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I'm not even sure how to begin

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a solution, sort of. I created a class that implements IContentAssistProcessor. I overrode the computeCompletionProposal function and in it i used the ITextViewer, that is passed in, to get the document. Then I used the IDocument.replace() function to add a closing bracket anytime an open one is typed. The problem with this is the cursor is moved to the end of the closing bracket. any suggestion on how to move it in between the brackets?

Comment: So you perform the replacement when computeCompletionProposal is called, regardless of whether the user actually picks one of the proposals? Do you return an empty proposals array?